# Force landscape orientation in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new to iOS development, and Im developing my first app. (so sorry if Im asking a newbie question)

My app is all in portrait orientation, except to the place where I'm using **UIImagePickerController** to take a picture to be used in the app, what I'm doing is:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

As my app is in **Portrait**, I need to make something to the **UIImagePickerController** be in **landscape only**. if I try to use:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

It seems that I can't use, because my Xcode identify as a error in this lines (probably because of Xcode the version, I'm not sure). And I'm not sure, but it seems that if I'm developing for **iOS 5.1** I will need to implement something **for iOS 6.0 too**, is it correct?

Can someone help me to understand what is need to make this **UIImagePickerController**, and only this view controller in the app, work in Landscape orientation and works in iOS 5.1 and 6?

Regards

Comment: are you making use of this? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1)

> **Important**: The `UIImagePickerController` class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the [cameraOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

So it looks like forcing landscape mode is unsupported and discouraged, unless you do so by replacing the default controls with a custom `cameraOverlayView`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class named "CUIImagePickerController" inherited from UIImagePickerController, override following methods, now use this class!

```
@interface CUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation CUIImagePickerController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orient {
    return (orient == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (orient == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
@end
```

Regards,

Comment: Maybe because my device is running iOS 6?

Comment: subclassing UIImagePickerController is forbidden ;)

Comment: @raistlin No, it's not forbidden. I've been doing it for years.

Answer (score -1):

try implementing below methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: tried it, but it rotate only the button to take the picture, and the camera image it rotates to even before take a picutre, showing very weird. any idea?