# Issue with presenting UIImagePickerController in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

My application runs in only landscape mode ! so I know `UIImagePickerController` presents only in portrait mode , so in iOS 6 , I had created a subclass of `UIImagePickerController` that forced `UIImagePickerController` to open in portrait mode:

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return NO;
}

@end
```

---

```
//presenting picker controller :

UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc]init];
ipc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This worked fine in iOS 6 , but now in iOS 7 my app does crash because of this :

```
2013-10-31 14:56:01.028 Medad[1731:60b] *** Terminating app due to
uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason:
'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the
application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```

This problem could be solved if I check `Portrait` in deployment info :
[image]

The problem is if I check this option my app does run in portrait too but I don't want it!

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Mc.Lover - Have you tried with my solution ?

Comment: I added a working solution with example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tested it and found that you should not handle the orientation via check box in target window as you shown in the above image because its your whole app orientation so please check all boxes to get all orientation supported. If you want some view in different orientations and some in different then you will have to handle it via coding in `ViewController` class by returning `YES` OR `NO` for orientation.

Here is my [Sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74641080/ImagePickerSample.zip). Which I made. Please check.

Below method will handle the orientation for `ViewController`

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

// Old Method
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
     return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

So, Solution is: Make two custom class one for `UIImagePickerController` and another is for `ViewController` (For All ViewControllers) and just make them for specific orientation and use those class as super class of your `UIImagePickerController` and all `ViewControllers` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple solution to avoid changing the supported orientations of your app, and make the `UIImagePickerController` work correctly: return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` only when the picker has to be presented.

You can do it simply subclassing UIApplication and using these two methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    UIViewController *topController = window.rootViewController;

    if ([self hasPicker:topController])
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    return [super supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:window];
}

-(BOOL)hasPicker:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    BOOL hasPicker = NO;

    NSLog(@"Check Controller: %@", controller);

    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]])
        return YES;

    for (UIViewController *child in controller.childViewControllers) {
        hasPicker = [self hasPicker:child];

        if (hasPicker)
            return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

In the first method, you are overriding the default `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindows:` method. Every time the method is called, you check all the view controllers in the hierarchy (through `hasPicker:`, a recursive method). If an UIImagePickerController is found, you return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`, otherwise you return the default setting of your app.

Another thing I suggest you: don't subclass `UIImagePickerController`, since Apple explicitly forbids it. Instead, use view controller containment as I did in this example:

> [Landscape Picker Example](https://github.com/lombax85/LandscapePicker)

**NOTE: The example code works only with `UIImagePickerController` containment. If you subclass it and add it through `presentViewController:` you may have to adjust the behavior of the `hasPicker:` method. One other simple thing you can do: add an instance variable to your `UIApplication` subclass and set it when you show the picker, and unset when you dismiss**

Answer (score 0):

You should also set in the subclass:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Now you can remove from the settings "Portrait"

**[EDIT]**
Since the UIImagePickerController can only be presented in Portrait (as per Apple doc), is possible to do the other way around, enabling portrait and landscape orientation, but fixing the orientation in landscape of everything but the picker controller. I made a little sample downloadable from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51180713/Prova.zip).

Comment: Are you using a container view controller? such as UINavigationController or UITabbarController?

Comment: no I don't use UINavigationController or etc .. just a simple UIViewControleller

Comment: It really seems that UIImagePickerController Does not support landscape, as stated in the doc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618546/force-landscape-orientation-in-uiimagepickercontroller . You should find another way around. So using the 3 orientation, just add the above methods to the other vcs, and don't subclass the picker.

Comment: It doesn't matter to lunch picker in portrait or landscape mode ! I just don't want to check Portrait mode in Deployment info because all view controllers  rotate !!! even if I set orientation to landscape mode only with code

Comment: That's the point, you check it, and in each VC (or you create an abstract VC class) except the picker (that you don't subclass)  you say to the other VC to open only in landscape. Is the reverse that you want to do, but it lead to same result. In this way the picker will open correctly in portrait and the other just landscape.

Comment: I've made a little app: a single v.c. that after seven seconds load image picker, that it seems to work perfectly as you want. You can download from here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51180713/Prova.zip

Answer (score 0):

In every controller add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
        || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

For the controller you have the picker:
Design this view with only Portrait orientation. So, it will have the same orientation of the picker. This view will be the only view with Portrait orientation while the others with landscape.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

    }

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Other solutions will also crash in the views that have the picker since they don't return portrait orientation to handle the picker orientation. while not adding any code to this view controller will let this view to run in landscape and portrait.

So, my proposed solution that to run all the views in landscape and this one in portrait. having this view in portrait is more design logical to have the same orientation of the picker.

The following go into your custom picker:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            return YES;
        }

        return NO;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
    }

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
```

Comment: Still crasheeeees unless  if Portrait is checked !

Comment: answer doesnot crash do u mean the other one?

Comment: picker in ios 7 only present in portrait orientation. your is landscape. this answer propose that you change the design to portraitonly for views that contain the picker. because you also don't want to have view orientation differ picker orientation.

Comment: this answer have 3different codes. one for all views and one for the view that contain the picker. and one for the custom picker. did u dothat.

Comment: another solution that you put your picker in a seperated view controller with portrait orientation. when you want to show the picker you show that view and then show your picker. when user pick. hide the picker and dismiss the view to return to the original one with the landscape. got it?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

In every controller add, even to the controller that have the picker:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
        || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Add this to your custom picker controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I think this solution will do the trick for you. I looked more deeply into it.

Comment: if this also crashed. You only have my other proposed solution.

Comment: I finally found a solution ! I created a custom navigation controller and linked it with the main ViewController

Comment: And how is the custom navigation controller is related to the picker?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had the same problem and solved it in a different way...
Actually this was identified as a bug in IOS6 happens with ImageViewController which only supports Portrait orientation ... so i spent lot of time and found a way around the same....

hope this helps so first things first...

add a property in your AppDelegate.h

```
@property BOOL model;
```

then in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.model=NO;

    return YES;
}
```

also add this method in AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    if(!self.model)
        return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; //or needed orientation
    else

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;


}
```

then in your view controller before presenting the imagepicker

implement this code...

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appdelegate.model=YES;
```

and then you just change the value when you came back after picking image , ie, delegate method

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appdelegate.model=NO;
```