# Open ImagePicker(Photos) in LandscapRight mode Type Application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios6

I am Trying To develop an application. My application should Only support LandscapRight mode so,I have set it in Application Target->Deployment Info by selecting only one check box LandscapRight. Now When I am Trying to open ImagePicker(Photos) in my application It will go for crash with this Error

```
Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES
```

It working good In Portrait and Landscap mode. But I don't want to watch my application in Portrait mode.

Please Suggest me any solution For this Problem .
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally Find Out the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19835982/3418619 It really work for me. thank you @Raon