# UIImagePickerViewController in landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

[image]I am working on app which is totally in Landscape mode. On one of the view,  I need to open the camera(UIImagePickerController) with overlay view. But When I click the button to open camera it get crashed with this issue i.e. reason:

> 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the
>   application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

I also put this line in viewcontroller but no effect.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Please give me some idea to make it working.

Comment: - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force landscape orientation in UIImagePickerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618546/force-landscape-orientation-in-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: @whitewolf09 Already gone through given link but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Probably you are using a navigation controller in your app. Are you?

Comment: @whitewolf09 Yes I have added UINavigationController

Comment: @Sudha, is the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientaion evert get called ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD Yes I debug this method but control never comes to this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `UINavigationController` as base view controller , that code snippet you provided simply doesn't work. Because you are adding that code to a `UIViewController` but it's already embeded in a `UINavigationController`.

To overcome this issue, you must create a subclass of `UINavigationController` and add that landscape related code to that subclass. Then assign this subclass to your Storyboard's base Navigation Controller.  Then this issue will be solved.

This is your navigation controller sub class' .h file

```
@interface YourCustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

And add this to your navigation controller subclass' .m file

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    //returns true if want to allow orientation change
    return YES ;  
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

And make sure to assign this class to your base Navigation controller using interface builder's identity inspector.

Project settings,

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can present a `UIImagePickerController` in landscape mode. Regardless of what documentation says, you can actually subclass it and can override it's functionality to work on landscape mode. (atleast its working on iOS 7)

To do this, you must create a subclass of `UIImagePickerController` and add above lines to that subclass. Project settings must be same as screenshot (atleast one landscape mode and one portrait mode must be ticked).

Then use that subclassed ImagePicker controller when you presenting the camera. It would successfully load camera in landscape mode. But standard camera controls will be misaligned and messed up. So better to hide defaultControlls (`picker.showsCameraControls = NO;`) just like you've done and use an overlay view instead.

Comment: not resolved. Giving same issue i.e.  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Comment: The reason is you have only ticked Landscape left in your project properties. Tick all 4 options, (may be exclude upside down). Then it will not crash. Because you have specifically mentioned to return `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` from your `UINavigationController` subclass, it will stay that way (althugh project settings says otherwise)

Comment: Selected both modes but still it is showing same issue

Comment: edited my answer, make sure whether you are doing the same thing.

Comment: Did the same but no effect.

Comment: the same one UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Comment: It's impossible to get that error if you ticked all 4 device orientations from Project Settings (see screenshot). Because when you select all 4, you will always have 'common' orientations

Comment: I have selected all the orientation

Comment: Make sure you are not overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations` from somewhere else othr than this subclass of UINavigationController

Comment: Crash removed but camera opens in portrait mode.

Comment: make sure you have assigned your subclass to your existing nav controller in storyboard, and make sure camera is presented from nav controller by a push (not modal)

Comment: Now giving this error (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported')

Comment: Why are you pushing a navigation controller? You should push a UIViewController with the camera view.

Comment: all the required code is here, anyways how can i send you code

Comment: check http://pastebin.com/W9G53X9z I have added the code which called during button click. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I see, since you are using ImagePickerController and it inherits from navigation controller so you can not push. Give me some time I will test this issue

Comment: can you send me the sample for opening the image picker in landscape mode.