# Wired behaviour of UIImagePickerController while capturing photo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

My entire app is in portrait orientation, only camera view should open in landscape orientation.

I've taking reference of Apple's sample code of `UIImagePickerController`, 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/PhotoPicker.zip

In my requirement, I've to force `UIImagePickerController` to start camera in landscape mode, and need to capture the photos.

I'm aware of this,

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
>   The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified,
>   with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

I've implemented following way to achieve this,

1. sub class with `UIImagePickerController` and where I implemented all required orientation methods. like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14618870/1603234
2. another method : make a category for `UIImagePickerController` into same class where I am presenting the camera.

   ```
   @implementation UIImagePickerController(rotationFixed)

   - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
       return NO;
   }

   - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
      return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   }

   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
   }
   @end
   ```

but this wont help.

See the screenshots below,

This is correct photo, taken with real camera (iPhone4s camera app)
[image]

This is captured within camera from app. Camera view was rotated in side.
[image]

- What I've to correct is, to make correct view for camera of `UIImagePickerController`
- Is there a way that I can force a view to capture photos in landscape mode?
- Why camera rotated inside?
- With `cameraOverlayView` can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the behavior of the image picker, as documented by Apple.

If you need more functionality than provided by the UIImagePickerController, you can use [AV Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) framework to capture the images.

Apple has a [sample application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) that demonstrates the use of AV Foundation.